Behaviour of volcanic eruptions and lava under a high-pressure supercritical water atmosphere

Planet with cloud cover

Same planet but showing surface
I have a planet that has undergone a massive runaway greenhouse effect and is currently completing the evaporation phase (it will later go through a dry transition phase as the water vapour gets photo-dissociated and the Hydrogen escapes into space).
This planet has the following parameters:

Mass: 0.845x Earth’s
Radius: 0.9718307x Earth’s
Gravity: 0.8946961 G
Insolation (from a G6 V star): 1.92x Earth’s
Current atmospheric composition: >98% water vapour, the rest mostly Carbon Dioxide, Nitrogen, Sulphur Dioxide and traces of Oxygen and other gases
Atmospheric pressure on surface: ~300 atm
Temperature on surface: ~900°C (previously reached temperatures as high as 1500°C but is cooling to an equilibrium state as thermal dissociation of water kicks in, thanks to Sulphur catalysts)

The planet’s surface is covered by water in a supercritical state. This means that it is not quite a liquid, but also not quite a gas either.
How will volcanoes (and lava spewing from them) behave in this supercritical water environment? Will they behave like underwater volcanoes on Earth (pillow formations, slower release, hydrothermal vent formations)?

So at the highest temperature reached, 1500°C, and similarly high pressures, the magma and water are going to intermix as a semi-liquid (saved from boiling only by the extreme pressure) upper surface layer, the crust will be wholly melted. As the surface cools somewhat the water, and other volitiles, will be released from the surface layer onto the surface and into the atmosphere. Pressure will actually go up for a time as the temperature drops, this is a controlled release that will reduce/remove eruptive potential from the upper mantle, as by 900°C the upper layer will be largely devoid of dissolved water and other gases. The surface water layer will still be mineral saturated raising its density and boiling point significantly.
At 300atm the water layer effectively acts as an extension of the crust/mantle. Surface volcanism is ultimately limited by the weight of overlying rock, or more specifically by the pressure exerted on the magma by overlying material. This is why when crater lakes on active vents drain there is generally an eruption, or series of them, afterward such as the September 2007 eruption of Mt Ruapehu. This is because the vent no longer has a pressure cap on it.
In this case you have a hot 300atm pressure cap across the whole mantle, you might still have areas of surface activity, at the sites of mantle plumes. This will be similar to the activity seen in the lava lake at Erta Ale where lava rises to the surface, crawls across the surface and then dives back under when it cools. Apart from where even hotter material is being brought up from depth the magma surface is simply going to be a smooth and placid plain, disturbed by occasional pressure waves. This will be overlain by a more easily disturbed but generally equally smooth water layer that bleeds into the high pressure atmosphere at a point that is nearly impossible to label clearly. If the atmosphere were much colder the magma would be able to solidify to some extent but at 900°C the magma will remain at least semi-liquid.

It is hard to be certain exactly how water would behave under such extreme conditions, but among other things it would depend on the temperature of the magma and particularly on the composition of the magma and the depth of the Supercritical water "supercritical ocean".
Some thoughts: the supercritical water phase would not allow magma to pass through it in the same way that magma forces its way through the crust when the liquid magma is less dense than the surrounding rocks. So some form of "volcano" would be likely at the boundary. This would probably form some vast tube or cone like structure that forced its way to the surface much like Hawaiian volcanoes that rise up from the bottom of the Pacific to the surface and build from there. There is also the possibility of all manner of chemical reactions depending on the nature of the rocks:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphic_facies
https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~hsg/763/table-images/water-phase-diagram.png

In the phase diagram, I think you may have confused 300 bar with 300 kilobar (300,000 bar). Water would be well within the supercritical range at 300 bar, but nearly solid at 300 kilobar.

@casualworldbuilder ha! yes you are quite right - thanks for that - I have corrected it.
